# Difference between hashed value, and key-value?

Tags: c, hash, hashtable, key-value

I'm trying to understand something that feels pretty basic but I cannot wrap my head around

we have a `key value, character, string, whatever` , and we want to send it to our `hashing function` , which gives some index.

My question is, is the result of the `hashing function` the `value` in a key-value pair ?

Or is the value separate from the result of the hashing function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A hash function is any function that can be used to map data of arbitrary size to fixed-size values. The values returned by a hash function are called hash values, hash codes, digests, or simply hashes. The values are usually used to index a fixed-size table called a hash table.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

So, you provide an input, which is presumably the key and get the result of the hashing function, which is the hash.

- I used the word **presumably** above, because it is up to you what your algorithm considers to be a key and what it considers to be a value, but, in general, the result of a hashing function is a **value** that can be used to index a hash table.

Here's a picture taken from wikipedia

[image]

Comment: Ok well the above commenter said the 'key' is the result of hashing the 'value' . But you're telling me we feed the hashing function an input (our key) and we get back a 'hash' , an index to store our key in.

my question is, is the value the same thing as the hash? If not, what is the point of a value?

Comment: @mistahwhite I disagree with the other commenter. The key is your input and the value/hash is your output. Quote from wiki: "A hash function takes a key as an input, which is associated with a datum or record and used to identify it to the data storage and retrieval application. The keys may be fixed length, like an integer, or variable length, like a name. In some cases, the key is the datum itself. The output is a hash code used to index a hash table holding the data or records, or pointers to them. "

Comment: @mistahwhite that being said, nothing stops you from using the hash later as a key in your algorithm, but, in the context of the hashing function, the input is the key and the output is the value/hash.

Comment: @mistahwhite the value of the hashing function is the value it returns. The hashing function returns a hash, therefore, the hash is the value.

Comment: Ok thanks for the thorough explanation I think I'm starting to get it

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

EDIT: Conforming to standard nomenclature...

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t hash;
    char key[32 + 1]; // emphasize null terminate string
} kv_t;

kv_t node;
strncpy( node.key, "Hello World!", sizeof node.key );
node.key[ sizeof node.key - 1 ] = '\0';
node.hash = hash( node.key);
```

Note: there is both a "key value" and a "hash value"... Referring to "value" is ambiguous and should be avoided.

In a perfect world, the hashing function would generate a unique hash value for each of the 'keys'. The world isn't perfect.

The above struct allows one to create and insert "key-value" pairs in a contiguous (growing) array of pairs that can later be "binary searched". Sparsely filled arrays may provide faster access, but be costly in terms of memory (unused 'slots'). Everything is a trade-off.

Comment: So I'm not understanding. I was under the assumption the key is our input to the hashing function. Why are you hashing the value?

Comment: I thought that the key was our input to the hashing function, and gave us back an index to store it within the hashtable.

Are you sure the 'key' is the result of hashing the value? Or vice versa. In any case, I wanted to know if the result of the hashing function and the 'value' is separate

Comment: @mistahwhite My first version did not conform to standard naming conventions. My apologies... Revised...

Comment: Thanks. So by this Edit, I am to understand the 'value' and the 'hash' are the same?

Comment: @mistahwhite "value" is a vague term. The value of the "record" is the string(?) one wants to store. The value of the hash (or "returned value from hashing") is another "value"... It may be best to not be vague, but to be specific about what one is referring to. (Again, my apologies for the first version, adding to your confusion.)